# How can delete all files except one from a directory?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, rm

I need to delete all files, except one (its name is defined), from a given directory.

How can I do this from the terminal in OS X? Can I do this with one single command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob && rm !(non_delete_file)
```

or

```
rm -f !(non_delete_file)
```

or

```
find . ! -name non_delete_file -delete
```

Note that the above `find` command will work recursively -- it will delete all files and directories in the current directory, and in all subdirectories. If that is a problem, use `-type f` (to match only files) and `-maxdepth 1` (to match things only in the current directory, ignoring subdirectories)

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 ! -name non_delete_file -delete
```

Comment: +1, you arrived just a second before me with find command :)

Comment: @DonCallisto, sorry, i don't know, next time i'll wait you :)

Comment: It's a good solution but how to avoid deleting system file like `./.DS_Store`? Also with respect to the `-name non_delete_file`, in my case `-name non_delete_file` is a directory. I would it to spare it *as well as the content inside*.

Comment: How to exclude more than one file or folder, can it work like rm -rf !(first) (!second)

Answer (score 2):

1. move the file that you want to preserve to somewhere outside the directory
2. remove everything in the directory using your favourite method
3. move the file that you want to preserve back into the directory

Not exactly 'hi-tech' but it is much harder to accidentally delete the file that you want to preserve if you use this approach.

Obviously, this approach fails if the file needs to continuously exist in the directory while all the carnage is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rm `ls | grep -v '^defined$'`
```

Comment: And what about `not_defined`?

Comment: Fixed with anchors.

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (this answer will specifically break on files with spaces in their names). you could use `printf %s\\n *` instead of `ls` for more reliability (though that will still break on files with newlines in their names...)